# Use python to strip wordpress caption shortcode from text

Tags: python, wordpress

Hi I'm exporting a wordpress blog to a different CMS, and I need to strip the opening and closing [caption] tags and their content from the html before uploading to the new platform, without removing the  tag that's contained within. The rest of the code is here FYI https://github.com/thmcmahon/wp2nb.

Ideally I would like to implement this as a function like so:

```
def strip_caption_tags(content):
  no_captions = do_some_stuff_presumably_regex(content)
  return caption
```

This is an example of the data:

```
<![CDATA[[caption id="attachment_5582" align="alignleft" width="1024" caption="Out on Lake Burley Griffin with members of the Canberra Ice Dragons Paddle Club, January 2014"]<a href="http://www.andrewleigh.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ACT-Dragon-Boat-3.jpg"><img class="size-large wp-image-5582" title="ACT Dragon Boat 3" src="http://www.andrewleigh.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ACT-Dragon-Boat-3-1024x682.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="682" /></a>[/caption]

<div class="mceTemp"><strong>Ca</strong><strong>l</strong><span style="font-weight: bold;">l for Local Sporting Champions to step up and apply for grants on offer</span></div>
Young people can find it difficult to meet the ongoing and significant costs associated with participation at sporting competitions.

The Local Sporting Champions program is designed to provide financial assistance for young people towards the cost of travel, accommodation, uniforms or equipment when competing, coaching or officiating at an official sports event.

For more information on the Local Sporting Champions program visit the Australian Sports Commission website: <a href="http://www.ausport.gov.au/champions">www.ausport.gov.au/champions</a>.]]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the answer to your question, but I'm not 100% sure you are asking the proper question about converting the data. This would probably be easier to take care of before exporting the database to XML, but if you want to replace the contents with regex in python:

```
import re
contents = //... get your post contents here
contents = re.sub(r'\[/?caption[^\]]*?\]', '', contents)
```

For the regex:

- `\[` matches a literal left square bracket `[`
- `/?` optionally matches a forward slash `/`
- `caption` matches `caption`
- `[^\]]*?` a lazy match for any characters that aren't a right square bracket `]`
- `\]` matches a literal right square bracket

This will match both `[caption foo="bar"]` as well as `[/caption]`.

See it in action using your example [here on Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bG4pE8#python) with additional explanation.